# Facebook Graph API 4.0 - createFromExistingAccessToken removed

Tags: android, facebook, access-token

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API 4.0 and I want to use a stored accesstoken.
Unfortunately all examples that I find use method createFromExistingAccessToken.

But SDK 4.0 does not support this method. I have read the related parts of the API several times and I can not find a replacement method.

Is this feature not available anymore ?
Can't we use a stored accesstoken ?

thanks.

Comment: There is nothing named Facebook Graph API 4.0. I'm guessing you are talking about an SDK. Which SDK?

Comment: @WizKid , sorry for the confusion. it is facebook android sdk 4.0

Comment: You can use setCurrentAccessToken as explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/

Comment: @WizKid I am not sure what you suggest addresses the issue. I want to use a previously stored (in sharedprefs) accesstoken. how can I do that with setCurrentAccessToken ?

Comment: @WizKid what do you think about this ?